# Connect proxy aborted while pushing to GitLab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am facing trouble pushing to GitLab repository, it worked for me yesterday, but now it is not working anymore I tried these commands in batch git:

```
git config --global https.proxy https://usernameofgitlab:passofgitlab@192.142.193.29:80

git user.email ""
git user.pass ""
git user.name ""
git push -u origin --all
```

and the output is:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://................': Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

anyone could help me with this error it is a bit strange that it no longer working and yesterday it has worked.
I changed the proxy program still receive an error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/........': Received HTTP code 500 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use an HTTP-based proxy to make a connection to an HTTPS site, you must use the non-standard CONNECT verb to create the tunnel, since TLS traffic can't be placed in a normal HTTP connection.  The first message is telling you that your proxy aborted that CONNECT command and as a result you cannot connect to the server.

The second message indicates that the proxy returned a 500 status code.  All 5xx status codes indicate a server error, and in this case the proxy is telling you it encountered an internal server error and was unable to service your request.  Since this is a problem in your proxy, you should contact your network administrator to inquire why the proxy is broken, and how to configure it correctly so you can use it once it's fixed.

Note also that `user.pass` does not exist and `user.name` and `user.email` have no effect on authentication.